# How to find pictureBoxes in the form and add specific EventHandler to them

Tags: c#, picturebox, eventhandler

I want to have a picture album that when I click  any picture it goes to another form to edit that picture.

Now I have some pictureBoxes in the form with the names like PB0, PB1, PB2,...

and a method like this

```
private void msgShow(int id)
{
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
}
```

when I add event handler to the two pictureBoxes like this

```
PB11.Click += new EventHandler((sender2, e2) => msgShow(3));
PB12.Click += new EventHandler((sender2, e2) => msgShow(4));
```

when I click PictureBox1 (PB1) messageBox shows

> 3

and when i click PictureBox2 (PB2) messageBox shows

> 4

it was true since I added 18 new pictureBoxes and used this code to do that

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
{
    ((PictureBox)Form2.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("PB" + i, true)[0]).Click += new EventHandler((sender2, e2) => msgShow(i));
}
```

now its wrong and when I click each pictureBox messageBox shows

```
20
```

but I want to show unique numbers for each PictureBox

Comment: Have you added PictureBoxes programmatically?

Comment: Read up about *closure*. TLDR: declare an extra int-variable **in the loop**, set it to i, and use that variable in the message box.

Comment: Standard bug: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Replace your for loop with this one

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox) Form2.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("PB" + i, true)[0];
    pictureBox.Tag = i;
    pictureBox.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {            
        msgShow((int)((sender as PictureBox).Tag));
    };
}
```

EDIT: According to new comments, send class object as

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox) Form2.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("PB" + i, true)[0];
    var productInfo = new ProductInfo
    {
        //This class is not mentioned into the question so I set example properties here eg.
       ImageName = "MyImage1.png",
       ImagePath = "C:\\Images\\"
       ...
    };
    pictureBox.Tag = productInfo;
    pictureBox.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {            
        msgShow((ProductInfo)((sender as PictureBox).Tag));
    };
}
```

And now your `msgShow` will takes `ProductInfo` object i-e

```
private void msgShow(ProductInfo pr)
{
    using(var fr = new FormProduct())
    {      
       fr.pInfo = pr;
       fr.showDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks Maarten but
as a matter of fact i want to send a class instead of int value.

    private void msgShow(ProductInfo pr)
    {
        FormProduct fr= new FormProduct();
        fr.pInfo =pr;
        fr.showDialog();
    }
and

    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
    {
        ((PictureBox)Form2.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("PB" + i, true)[0]).Click += new EventHandler((sender2, e2) => msgShow(list<ProductInfo>[i]));
    }

and a class cannot send within Tag property.

Comment: @Arash.Zandi You did not mentioned that you want to send class instead of `i`. My answer is according to your question. But I will update it according to your new requirement.